# Base64 vs Jpeg in local storage on android

Tags: android, base64, jpeg, android-sqlite

When I get a image from a server I get a base64 encoded image.
If I want to save it to the local storage on the phone what is fastest and takes less space between these alternatives:

1. Decode the image and save it locally as .jpeg and always load from that image that is locally stored?
2. Or save the entire base64 image in the local database and load from that every time?

The view that is suppose to show the images might be a list of pictures.

So my question is simple:
What is the best thing to do and why?

Comment: I think 2 option feasible because I used that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

window.localStorage in the browser stores strings, so base64 would be most efficient. If you decoded the base64 you'd end up with an array of byte values that represent the image, this would serialize to a much larger string than the base64 encoded one.

Comment: isn't the base64 actually 33% bigger than the actual image? Or have I misunderstood your question?

Comment: @Joakim Engstrom - the browser's localStorage doesn't store images or any other binary object; it stores strings, and the most efficient string representation of an image is base64.